# How to search the value of each row in multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new in R and could not find a good way to solve this problem
There is a data frame like this:

```
person_ID    city        A    B    C    group
11           chicago     1              AA
12           Denver           1         AA
13           atlanta              2     BB
14           chicago              1     AA 
15           new-york    2              BB
```

Person_id is unique variable and city ,A,B,C are defined for each person. The numbers in columns A,B,C are unique numbers that could be assigned to multiple persons and could show up in one of these columns(A,B,C). I want to assign a group number to each person using city ,A,B,C ,  if there is anything common between two person , they will be in the same group. for i.e person 13 and 15 because of having number 2 in common are in the same group (BB)

Comment: \Try with `v1 <-c("AA", "BB")[do.call(pmax, c(df1[c("A", "B", "C")], na.rm = TRUE))]; v1[is.na(v1)] <- "AA"; v1`

Comment: What about user 12 and 13 that they both have city = Atlanta? How many groups can a user have and which group get priority?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I edited the question to answer @AntoniosK. There will be only one group for each person.

Comment: @akrun can you explain your approach? the unique numbers could be in any of three columns (A,B,C). and I want to find the person with at least one thing in common in any of those three columns and city.

Comment: In your example above now user 12 and 14 have nothing in common, but they are in the same group due to having something in common with user 11, right? That makes things a bit more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to work with a different format of the data.  Try

```
long_format <- data_frame %>%
  gather(letter, value, A:C)
```

The presence of `person_ID 14` complicates things a little at this point, because this individual doesn't have any values for any letters.  To remove the NAs from the other IDs, this ID goes away completely.  If that is okay, you can do

```
long_format <- data_frame %>%
  gather(letter, value, A:C, na.rm = TRUE)
```

To use this to get all the people with 2 as a value in a letter, regardless of anything else, take

```
long_format %>%
  filter(value == 2)
```

To group them by value (may not work with NAs), take

```
long_format %>%
  group_by(city, value) %>%
  summarize(
    n = n(), # will summarize how many individuals are in each pair
    IDs = paste(person_ID, collapse = " ") # which IDs are in each group
  )
```

These are just examples - I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with the data at this point.